# Why I have AWS OpenSearch indices with 0 shards

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-opensearch

I have an `aws` `opensearch` cluster and there are some indices. When I try to get the indices, I see some indices have `0` shards.

What does that mean?

```
index                                                    shard prirep state      docs    store ip            node

aws-lambda-service-test-prev-scrape_o2-2022-08-01        0     p      STARTED      53  106.5kb x.x.x.x 5c406c54a56c6a43a261e5b7b6006d2
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons why you might have an OpenSearch index with 0 shards:

1. The index is empty and has no data to shard.
2. The index is being deleted and all its data has been removed.
3. The index has been created but not yet populated with data.

Comment: Hi Flow, thank you. I have doubts about your 2nd point which is `The index is being deleted and all its data has been removed.`. Once an index is removed, how come it still shows then? And also is it possible to get the index created date?